# Drupal rows edit delete url add comma on entity type id at admin

Tags: drupal-7

In Drupal 7 admin have list and when we click on edit/delete link,
Then page redirect to new page but it add comma on entity type id.

For example edit url is- http://localhost/drupal7/en/admin/structure/entity-type/player_team/superleague/4,495/edit?destination=admin/superleagues

Here entity id contain comma **4,495**. Due to it show 404 page not found.

It works well if entity id id less than 1000.

Please suggest me correct solution

Thank you

Comment: please anybody can look into this ?

Comment: 4,495 is a nid or something else?

Comment: @usmanjutt84, Sorry for late reply. this is list id. Actually i have a module in which i add new entries. and this is entry id not Node id.   Please reply